# Install sample documents to users personal folder upon running application

Tags: installshield

I have a Basic MSI Project in InstallShield 2012 Spring. This project installs sample documents to the current user's Documents folder (Not the Public Documents folder). When I then log onto another user, I see the application installed, but I do not see those sample documents in the second user's Documents folder (this makes sense). My question is, is there a setting in InstallShield or a way to have the sample documents install for this second user when the second user launches the application? Can launching the application detect that there are files missing in the user's Documents folder and then trigger a repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is possible, I would not recommend it. The user should control what goes in his or her documents folder; the large number of applications out there that do not respect this is not a good reason for another not to do so. Instead the application should have a way to browse the samples, open them as templates, etc., and then allow the user to save them in the documents folder. If you need them to start in the documents folder, have the application copy them in, and track somewhere that it has done so.

If you do try to automatically install these through Windows Installer, the simplest approach is to make per-user components with key files reflecting the documents location, and ensure your application's shortcuts are advertised. Launching through an advertised shortcut will scan for missing key files, and then auto-repair will install them. But auto-repair is not an experience that users like, and this approach will replace the files if the user deletes them all. (Alternately you can use a per-user registry key as the indicator, which may be less likely to be deleted.)